# I need a fixed current through a varying resistance. What's the most straightforward way o

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to electrically ignite fireworks using ematch (I'm working with a professional pyrotechnician for safety) which has an unknown but limited resistance (in the cases I'm considering, 0.5 ohms < R < 7 ohms) but 1 amp will be sufficient in all cases. I'm hoping to use a 9 V battery to power this. The firing circuit will only be on a small fraction of the time so efficiency is not critical.

I was looking at a current limiting circuit using a Zener diode and a BJT but that seems frowned upon here because of the high heat production. Another option is an LM317 with a resistor connecting output and adjust but the overhead voltage is rather high at 3 V (I wouldn't be able to fire the 7 ohm case), and I'd still be dealing with a lot of heat. Digikey has current regulator ICs but the only ones at 1 amp or higher are SMD which I can't solder due to essential tremor, and I can't find a breakout board.

What are my best options?

Comment: What sort of "9V battery" are you hoping to use here? I hope it's not a little "PP3" type because you'll never get 1A out of one of those...

Comment: @brhans when they are new they can make about 3A into 1 ohm.

Comment: And the power is going to be dissipated somewhere.  9 V supply, 1 A, and 0.5 ohms means the voltage across the load is 0.5 V.  So the voltage across the "current source" is 8.5 V, at the same 1 A as the load.  So the dissipation in the "current source" is 9.5 W.  Whether that's a resistor, a transistor, an IC, the dissipation in those components is still going to be 9.5 W.

Comment: Testing I've seen online suggests that quality, new 9V batteries can produce about 2 A in a short circuit.

Comment: Not what you asked but.....   What happens if this thing goes off prematurely???    I hope you're building some redundancy into it so you don't hurt somebody.

Comment: I'm going to have multiple hardware and software switches to ensure nothing happens by accident. As I said, I'm working with a pyrotechnician and they're ALL about safety.

Answer (score 0):

easiest is probably just to not limit the current, just connect it directly to  the 9V battery, I've never heard of an e-match failing by being over-powered

Comment: This is a very intriguing take. I would need a second battery for the other components because of the voltage drop but that's hardly insurmountable.